# Parse.com load Image in Uiimage Swift

Tags: database, swift, parse-platform, uiimageview

I've searched all over the internet for this but i can't find a sensible answer to my question. I just want to load an image stored in a parse database (not user based) 
Thanks in advance but i'm really new to this.

Code I tried:

```
    var query = PFQuery(className:"Movies")
    query.whereKey("IndexID", equalTo:StrRandomID)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock
        {
            (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.
            println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) Objects.")
            println("RandomId = \(StrRandomID) ")

            // Do something with the found objects


            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject]
            {
                for ParseData in objects
                {
                    println(ParseData.objectId)
                    self.lblTitle.text = String(stringInterpolationSegment: ParseData["MovieName"]!)
                    self.lblYear.text = String(stringInterpolationSegment: ParseData["Year"]!)
                    self.lblRating.text = String(format: "%.1f", float_t(ParseData["IMDB_Rating"]! as! NSNumber))
                    self.lblDescription.text = String(stringInterpolationSegment: ParseData["Plot"]!)

                    let Image = ParseData["Poster"] as! PFFile
                    Image.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock
                    ({
                        (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                        if (error == nil)
                        {
                            let imgPoster = UIImage(data: imageData)
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }

        else
        {
            // Log details of the failure
            println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried reading the Parse documentation? It's explained there

Comment: yes i have and i've tried it but i just can't get it to work with images.

Comment: Could you show the code which you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so i finally fixed it:

```
        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.
            println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) Objects.")
            println("RandomId = \(StrRandomID) ")


            // Do something with the found objects

            for object: AnyObject in objects!
            {
                let Poster = object["Poster"] as! PFFile
                Poster.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
                    (imagedata: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if (error == nil)
                    {

                        var blur = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light)
                        var blurview = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blur)
                        let image = UIImage(data: imagedata!)
                        self.imgBackground.image = image
                        self.imgPoster.image = image
                        blurview.frame = self.imgBackground.bounds
                        self.imgBackground.addSubview(blurview)

                    }
                })

            }


            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject]
            {
                for ParseData in objects
                {
                    println(ParseData.objectId)
                    self.lblTitle.text = String(stringInterpolationSegment: ParseData["MovieName"]!)
                    self.lblYear.text = String(stringInterpolationSegment: ParseData["Year"]!)
                    self.lblRating.text = String(format: "%.1f", float_t(ParseData["IMDB_Rating"]! as! NSNumber))
                    self.lblDescription.text = String(stringInterpolationSegment: ParseData["Plot"]!)


                }
            }

        }
```